# How to change the SELECT value in MVC model? The value that would like to change is the staff_ID

Tags: php, model-view-controller

```css
<select name="cStaff" id="consultStaff"> 
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"> Consultant </option>
            <option value="1"> Haemin </option>
            <option value="2"> Cavan </option>
        </select>
```

```html
function addConsultation()
    {
        //Enrol Validation
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $data['content'] = "consultationSignUp";

        $student_id = $this->session->userdata('studentID');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cDate', 'Consultation Date', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cTime', 'Consultation Time', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cRemark', 'Consultation Remark', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cStaff', 'Consultant', 'trim|required');

        $data['consultDate'] = $this->input->post('cDate');
        $data['consultTime'] = $this->input->post('cTime');
        $data['consultRemark'] = $this->input->post('cRemark');
        $data['studID'] = $student_id;
        $data['staffID'] = $this->input->post('cStaff');

        $this->load->model('Kindergarten','', TRUE);
        $result = $this->Kindergarten->insertNewConsultation($data);

        if($result)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('consultStatus', '<div class="alert_green" style="width:60%">New Consultation Form was added.</div>');
            $this->viewData();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('consultStatus', '<div class="alert" style="width:500px">Error! Please try again.</div>');
            $this->load->view('kheader_logged');
            $this->load->view('kconsultation_form', $data);
            $this->load->view('kfooter');
        }
    }
```

Basically, all the data I could fetched from the VIEW. However, when I wanna INSERT the data into the database, I have to change the staff_ID into 111/112, but currently, my OPTION VALUE is 1/2. How could I change it in the Controller?

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of code, cut and paste the code into your question.

Comment: Hi sorry about this. I had post the code in the code snippet.